# Order of an element on a Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose i have an ellement $g$ of a group $\langle G,+\rangle$ and say $k$ is the order of my  group does $g^k$=1? Hence if that is true then i can find the order  of $g$ because it is the least divisor of $k$ right? Example Say $<Z9999,+>$ find the order of 3^80 and 3

Comment: Do you mean the *exponent* of a group $G$ (denoted by $exp(G)$), that is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $g^k=1$ for all $g \in G$? If $G$ is finite abelian, then $exp(G)=$lcm of all orders of elements of $G$.

Comment: $G$ is finite and $k$ is the cardinal number of $G$  that is its order as a Group.And i want to find the order of a given element.

Comment: Your second edit of the question suggests that "rank=order", can you confirm? So you want to know the order of $3^{80}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/9999\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: yes that is what im aiming

Comment: If the operation of your group is $+$, then you should be looking at $kg$, not $g^k$.

Comment: I don't know where you are getting this "least divisor of $k$". The order is a divisor of $k$, and it is the least $r$ such that $g^r=1$, but that $r$ doesn't have to be the least divisor of $k$. Heck, the least divisor of $k$ is 1, and very few elements have order 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ is a finite group of order $n$, then for every element $g \in G$ it is true that $g^n=1$. But there might be a smaller positive integer $k$, depending on $g$ such that $g^k=1$. The smallest is called the order $o(g)$ of $g$. And $o(g)$ divides $n$. That is one of the first things you learn from Group Theory.

Calculating the order of an element can be done manually (if you know a presentation of the group) and there are also computer algebra programs (like GAP), that could help you. A special case is a cyclic group of order $n$, say generated by $g$, where every element is a power of this $g$. Then $o(g^i)=\frac{n}{gcd(i,n)}$.

Comment: this formula aplies only in the elements that generate $G$ ?

Comment: And if i find the smallest number that divides $n$ i found the order of $g$ right?

Comment: Yes, and the formula is for cyclic groups only.

Comment: By the way, the order of $3^{80}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/9999\mathbb{Z}$ is $1111$, can you see that?

Comment: Depends if  3 generates $Z9999$ if it does then yes.But isnt $<3>={0,3,6,9....}$ so there are elements missing..Well i can say that 3^9999=1 and the smallest divisor of 9999 >1 is 3 hence 3 has an order of 3? that isnt right..

Comment: No, you are mixing up *additive* and *multiplicative* notation. Additively one would write $\mathbb{Z}/9999\mathbb{Z}$ and multiplicatively $C_{9999}$. The number $3$ mod $9999$ "lives" in the additive one. You can multiply, but then you are looking at a ring as mathematical structure. And $3$ is a zero divisor in $\mathbb{Z}/9999\mathbb{Z}$.